# How to properly flush PHP echo output

Tags: php, ob-start

I am using PHPMailer to send emails with attachments.

Each email takes about 5 seconds to send, and the PHP can send up to 5 emails with a total in that case of 10 PDFs...

During all that time, the browser shows a white page.

```php
<?php
echo '<div>some spinner html</div>';
// code here to send emails
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message sent!';
}

echo 'all the rest of the html';
?>
```

This doesn't work...
I have the feeling I can use an `ob_start()` to buffer the rest of the page and only show a spinner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Real answer: Use `JS` and create an API using `PHP`

Best solution to your problem is using `JavaScript` and `XHR` and make a beautiful UI for it. If you want to show a loading and remove it after emails sent and show other stuff after disappearance of loading, it's only possible through `JS`. `PHP` is just a server side language capable of sending a response to browser and have no access to rendered page!

### Flush output

Just use `ob_flush()` and `flush()` functions:

```php
echo '<div>some spinner html</div>';
ob_flush();
flush();
// code here to send emails
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
} else {
    echo 'Message sent!';
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

echo 'all the rest of the html';
```

### Using implicit flush

This looks like the previous one, but reduced a function call. this removes the `flush()` call!

```php
ob_implicit_flush(true)
echo '<div>some spinner html</div>';
ob_flush();
// code here to send emails
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    ob_flush();
} else {
    echo 'Message sent!';
    ob_flush();
}

echo 'all the rest of the html';
```

### Turn off output buffer

Other solution is to turn off output buffer:

```php
while (@ob_end_flush());
echo '<div>some spinner html</div>';
// code here to send emails
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message sent!';
}

echo 'all the rest of the html';
```

Comment: Thanks, haven't tested it yet (I will shortly, I'll keep you posted), but would you mind just editing the snippets so that the html isn't a variable but formatted normally (not between php tags) ?
Also, I'm wondering whether the first div won't persist after the second echo. The page has to be erased, and redrawn with the new HTML...

Comment: @Silloky as I mentioned in my answer the right way to do it is using `JS` and `XHR`. If you want to show a loading and remove it after end and show other stuff it s only possible through `JS`. `PHP` is just sending a response to browser and have no access to it!

Comment: Ok, I get it. I am not at that point yet, will accept your answer some time today...